# Tomcat: The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I had written a program that counts th times i visited the site. When i press run button there opens new window with this stack trace: 
[image: my stack trace]

I dont know what to do, beacause i am a newbie for tomcat. Im using Eclipse and tomcat 8.5. I also provide my project tree and web.xml

[image: web.xml]
[image: project tree]

I hope we`ll find the answer, because i want to continue learning, and for now i stuck on this.

Comment: post your sample code so that we can find the issue with your code

Comment: The problem is that the compiled version of `FileCounter` is not where Tomcat can find it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, check the dependencies in the pom.xml file. You may be trying to use too new one for JVM or Server.

for example
JVM 1.8
Tomcat 8.5

Using jackson version 2.12.1 will cause this bug.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But with version 2.9.4 there won't be a problem

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

However, Good Practice says: Use the latest stable versions whenever possible. So maybe Upgrade server and JVM.